# Using my Lollipop theme (on Lollipop)!

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library

I had my app looking pretty nice using the new Lollipop tools. I decided backwards compatibility is important, so I switched all my Fragments,actionBar imports to the support library. Now (understandably) I can't use my lollipop theme.

Is there a way to use different action bars for different themes? I tried to cast the support ActionBar to a new one but it doesn't seem this is allowed.

My problem lies with the following (from v21 docs)

> > All of your Activities must extend from ActionBarActivity, which
> >     extends from FragmentActivity from the v4 support library, so you can
> >     continue to use fragments.  All of your themes (that want an Action
> >     Bar/Toolbar) must inherit from Theme.AppCompat.  There are variants
> >     available, including Light and NoActionBar. When inflating anything to
> >     be displayed on the action bar (such as a SpinnerAdapter for list
> >     navigation in the toolbar), make sure you use the action bar’s themed
> >     context, retrieved via getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(). You
> >     must use the static methods in MenuItemCompat for any action-related
> >     calls on a MenuItem.

so by calling getsupportActionBar I can't use my Holo theme:

```
 <resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="appTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>


<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue_semi_transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Also for some reason the action bar loses the button that was on it and it goes into the dropdown menu and the app icon no longer appears in the action bar.
I really am no expert on this stuff having only started developing on lollipop so would really appreciate advice.

Comment: If you are using a Holo theme, you are by definition not building a Lollipop app - Lollipop and API 21 use the `Theme.Material` as their base.

Comment: Ok fair point- however my issue still arises with a Material layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCompat (i.e., `ActionBarActivity`) uses the [Material color palette](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette) which defines default coloring throughout your app. In your case, you need to use `colorPrimary` for your action bar color:

```
<style name="appTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_semi_transparent</item>
</style>
```

Note that you should also provide a `colorPrimaryDark` (a darker version of the same color) for coloring the status bar.

Per the partially outdated [Action Bar training](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems), AppCompat also uses app namespaced attributes (as things like `showAsAction` didn't exist before API 11) for your menu items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
  ...
</menu>
```

Per the [Toolbar documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) (which is default behavior on Material themes and in AppCompat):

> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. **The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.**

Therefore as you noted the app icon not appearing on the Action Bar is expected behavior.

Comment: This is a really great answer. Thanks for taking the time to post it.